# MySQL on Compute Engine did not shutdown correctly due to maintenance

Tags: mysql, linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've discovered that a recent automatic migration of my Compute Engine VM instance has caused by mysql not to shutdown correctly and thus the restart took much longer do to checks.

Is there a way to initiate and wait for mysql service to shutdown for the VM maintenance/migration?

Comment: Edit your question with the OS distribution and version of MySQL.

Comment: ubuntu and mysql 5.7

Comment: Review this link and then create a shutdown script as mentioned in Partha Mehta's answer. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mysql.server.1.html

Comment: Additional items. How big is your MySQL setup? Disk storage, database size, logfile size, etc? This can affect how long it takes to correctly shutdown MySQL and flush outstanding writes and transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you are looking for [shutdown scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript). Using which you request to wait about 90 seconds before GCE will forcibly terminates your instance.

You set your shutdown script instance metadata

`gcloud compute instances create example-instance \
    --metadata-from-file shutdown-script=examples/scripts/install.sh`

Hope this helps.